# How to mock external dependencies? / SpringBoot

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, powermock

I have a program for which I've written the following integration test (the real test is much more complex, but these are the important parts):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=SpringApplication.class)
@Transactional
public class ReportServiceIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
private ReportService4 reportService;

    @Test
    public void testHappyPath() {
        String url = "https://www.someRealUrl.com";
        Document doc = Parser.parseUrl(url);
        Report report = reportService.generateReport(doc);

        assertNotNull(report.getAllRecommendations());
        assertNotNull(report.getId());

        //...

    }

}
```

The integration test works fine, but as you can see, it relies on an external dependency do a real website in order to work. This has some obvious drawbacks (can't test when you're offline, etc...).

So what I'm trying to do is only mock out the Parser.parseUrl() method to always return a Document from an offline source instead of calling the real URL.

I looked at using PowerMockito and running the test with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` but that forces me to mock out the entire report service and the repository behind it, when really all I want to do is eliminate the dependency on an external source.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring profiles](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/testing-active-profiles/). Create a test profile with the external resource mocked.